# destroy an android service

Tags: android, service, destroy

I am using a service in my android app, which is called when an alarm is activated by a calander. When the service has been activated i want it to be destroyed by the `OnStart()` method once it has completed its code.

```
My OnStart() method:

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
super.onStart(intent, startId);

Vibrator vi = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

vi.vibrate(5000);

Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //CODE HERE TO DESTROY SERVICE??

}
```

This bassically means when the service is called it runs the code in the `OnStart()` method and i want it to destroy itself. Any Ideas, methods that would do this?.

Thanks, jack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call **`stopSelf()`** in onCreate to stop the service

Comment: you shouldn't call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 then is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: stopSelf() works perfectly fine for me. Can you please explain why shouldn't we call stopSelf() ?

Comment: If someone can expalin why @SimonDorociak could be saying not to use stopSelf(), I am still waiting after almost 8 years.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to kill a service stopService() and stopSelf 
You can call stopSelf()  method which  in your onCreate method .

Answer (score -1):

you can call onStop() or mService.unbind();